# Boost dynamic_bitset - put an integer value into a range of bits

Tags: c++, boost, bit, bitset, boost-dynamic-bitset

I have a 7-byte/56-bit bitset that upon construction sets the first bit to one:

```
boost::dynamic_bitset<> b(56, 1);
```

After construction, I'd like to place an integer value (say 2019) into bits 4 through 15. I'm curious if there is a simple way within boost to do this without bitwise operations? Basically, I want to set a range of bits to an integer value that I know is small enough to fit into those bits. Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `boost::dynamic_bitset<>` offers much less functionality. I think the only possibility is to use an ordinary loop:

```
template <typename Bitset>
void set_in_range(Bitset& b, unsigned value, int from, int to)
{
  for (int i = from; i < to; ++i, value >>= 1)
    b[i] = (value & 1);
}

boost::dynamic_bitset<> b(56, 1);
set_in_range(b, 2019, 4, 15);
```

Comment: You need to use 'i <= to' in the for loop rather than 'i < to'