# The most efficient method to change the value of a range of bits in std::bitset

Tags: c++, performance, bit, bitset, std-bitset

I need an efficient method with low complexity to change the values of a range of bits in the bitset :

```
bitset<1000000> bs;
```

and I need to set values from 100 to 500 to TRUE for example .

what is the fastest method to accomplish this in the lowest complexity ?

using a loop wouldn't suffice for sure .

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a code writing service, please show your efforts

Comment: But I am NOT asking for a code write !?

Comment: @EbramShehata probably you could provide several attempts and see which is more efficient.

Comment: `std::bitset` does not allow direct access to the stored data, but if you can implement your own bitset class, say using the bits in `uint64` variables, you could set 64 bits in one instruction.

Comment: note that  `bitset<1000000> bs;` has a high chance of causing a stack overflow. I suggest using `auto bs = std::make_unique<std::bitset<1000000>();` if that troubles you enough.

Answer (score 1):

An ordinary for-loop is the easiest and fastest way:

```
std::bitset<1000000> bs;

for (unsigned i = start, stop = start + n; i != stop; ++i)
  bs.set(i);
```

Unfortunately:

- given the size of `bs`, working with masks / shifting isn't an option (e.g. see [in bitset, can i use "to_ulong" for a specific range of bits?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2177186/3235496))
- the interface of `bitset` doesn't support ranges / sub-blocks (e.g. [What is the performance of std::bitset?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30295174/3235496)). The same limitation is present in [boost::dynamic_bitset](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9966814/3235496).

Also consider that `std::bitset` doesn't come with [iterators](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-active.html#1112), so it cannot be used with the functions in `<algorithm>` library.

If performance really matters you could consider an *ad-hoc* implementation.