# Testing ranges of bits in std::bitset

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, bitset, std-bitset

Is there an efficient way to test subranges in `std::bitset`?  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37829823/the-most-efficient-method-to-change-the-value-of-a-range-of-bits-in-stdbitset) seems to suggest not.

I [see](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/bitset/bitset/any/) `std::bitset::any` and `std::bitset:all` (for C++11), but they are for the whole set, not a subrange.  What I was hoping for was an overloaded version of `any` and `all`.  Something like:

```
bool all(size_t off, size_t len) const;
```

`std::bitset::test` is also just a single bit.  Theoretically, I could construct bitsets to bit twiddle against, but these bitsets will be fairly large and this might not be reasonable.

Thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: Here's a similar [related question](/q/39673347) about efficiently setting ranges.

Answer (score 0):

It is (at least theoretically) possible that your Standard Library has  versions of the `std::all_of`, `std::any_of` and `std::none_of` algorithms specialized on `std::bitset::iterator` that make use of the Library's knowledge of the internals to provide more efficient implementations than you can yourself.

If not, it may be well worth your effort to write and contribute such specializations.  Assuming, of course, that your standard library accepts such contributions on terms you're willing to agree to.

Comment: `bitset` doesn't have iterators.

Comment: Ah, good point.  That's then one of the significant differences between `std::bitset`, `std::array<bool>` and `std::vector<bool>`.  And this answer doesn't really contribute anything.  If there's sufficient use cases, it may well be something to propose as an enhancement request for the Standard Library, then.